# dockerignore with Docker compose not ignoring .env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerignore

Below you can see a representation of my project folder structure. I have two microservices which are called `auth` and `profile`, they are located inside the `services` directory. The `docker-containers` directory hold my `docker-compose.yaml` file in which I list all the images of my application.

```
.
├── services
│   ├── auth  
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   ├── .env
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── .dockerignore
│   ├── profile 
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   ├── .env
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── .dockerignore   
└── docker-containers
    ├── docker-compose.yaml
```

Below is my `docker-compose.yaml` file in which I define the location of the `auth` service (and other images).  I also want to override the local `.env` file with the values from the `environment` list. But when I run the docker compose project the values from my local `.env` file are still being used.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  auth:
    build: 
      context: ../services/auth
    container_name: auth-service
    depends_on: 
      - redis
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ../services/auth/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    command: yarn dev
    env_file: ../services/auth/.env
    environment:
      FASTIFY_PORT: 3000
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      FASTIFY_ADDRESS: "0.0.0.0"
      TOKEN_SECRET: 1d037ffb614158a9032c02f479b36f42dd33ba325f76a7692498c33839afc5d547eae2b47f0f4926b76b08fc91d19352
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017
    
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 2717:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-data:/data
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

This is my `Dockerfile` and the `.dockerignore` file inside the `auth` service and based on my understanding the local `.env` file should not be copied to the docker context, because it is listed inside the `.dockerignore` file.
But when I log a value from my environment variables from the docker application it still logs the old value from my local `.env` file.

```sh
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", "./"]

RUN yarn

COPY dist .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

```
node_modules

Dockerfile

.env*
.prettier*
.git

.vscode/
```

The weird part is that the `node_modules` folder of the `auth` services is being ignored but for some reason the environment variables inside the docker container are still based on the local `.env` file.

Comment: Nothing in your Dockerfile has any effect because you overwrite all of it at container run time with `volumes:` mounts.  I'd recommend deleting those blocks from the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it out.